# Python pandas - check if object is byte object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, object

I have a dataframe (imported from SAS files using pandas.read_sas) where one column sometimes is a byte object and other times is just a string.

i.e.

```
>>> df1
   barcode
0  b'346546'  
1  b'645542'
2  b'486465'
3  b'135455'
4  b'465482'
5  b'132456'

>>> df2
   barcode
0  346546  
1  645542
2  486465
3  135455
4  465482
5  132456
```

In my code, when I use

```
df1.loc[:,'barcode']=df1['barcode'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

it works but when I use

```
df2.loc[:,'barcode']=df2['barcode'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

I get NaN values.

Is there a way to check specifically if it's a byte object? Unfortunately both cases can occur.

Another solution would be to keep this type without decoding and encode when I export the dataframe.

```
df1.to_csv(test.csv,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

But, first of all the above is not working, second I guess I still need to check whether encoding is required.

Answer (score 4):

You can use where by applying type and check for the condtion, so conditional application of decode is done. i.e

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'barcode':[b'346546',b'645542',b'486465',b'135455',15200,15200]})

df['barcode'] = df['barcode'].where(df['barcode'].apply(type) != bytes, df['barcode'].str.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output :

```
  barcode
0  346546
1  645542
2  486465
3  135455
4   15200
5   15200
```

```
df['barcode'].apply(type) != bytes # This gives a booelan mask
```

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: barcode, dtype: bool
```

`df.where` takes the false values and the replaces with the newly decoded strings.

You can also use `np.where`, `mask` which are very similar to `df.where` for this operation.